# Need advice with getting visual states to work fully in code behind

Tags: vb.net, uwp

In my UWP application, I'm creating all the controls in code behind (no XAML whatsoever). Need to make my application respond to the window size changing. Stumbled across visual states and trying to test out changing the background colour of my Grid control at the moment depending on the width of the window. This is what I've got so far but nothing is happening:

```
Dim visualStates = New VisualStateGroup()
Dim horiVisualState = New VisualState()

horiVisualState.Setters.Add(New Setter() With {.Target = New TargetPropertyPath(BackgroundProperty) With {.Target = grid2}, .Value = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange)})

horiVisualState.StateTriggers.Add(New AdaptiveTrigger() With {.MinWindowWidth = 800})

visualStates.States.Add(horiVisualState)
VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(Me).Add(visualStates)
```

grid2 is a grid which is a child of another grid, the "Me" refers to the main grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the 'Me' grid is the root panel of all other child UI elements on XAML page like the following:

```xml
<Page
x:Class="AppAdaptive.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppAdaptive"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="Me">
</Grid>
```

```vb
Dim grid2 As Grid = New Grid() With {.Width = 200, .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)}
[Me].Children.Add(grid2)
Dim visualStateGroup = New VisualStateGroup()
Dim horiVisualState = New VisualState()
horiVisualState.Setters.Add(New Setter() With {.Target = New TargetPropertyPath() With {.Target = grid2, .Path = New PropertyPath("Background")}, .Value = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange)})
horiVisualState.StateTriggers.Add(New AdaptiveTrigger() With {.MinWindowWidth = 800})
visualStateGroup.States.Add(horiVisualState)
VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(Me).Add(visualStateGroup)
```

Comment: So I got the top grid, which has been created within code and used that when adding the visual state group. Still not working unfortunately. grid2 is not a direct child of that top grid, its a bit far down the line.

Comment: @AaronBoclet If you use my code to test, does it work?

Comment: I created a new test project with your code and I can't get it to work.

Comment: @AaronBoclet Sorry, I'm not familar with vb.net, I just test c# code without problem and then convert it to vb.net code. Please change this line code `horiVisualState.Setters.Add(New Setter() With {.Target = New TargetPropertyPath() With {.Target = grid2, .Path = New PropertyPath("Background")}, .Value = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange)})`. I've updated in above reply.

Comment: that's alright and I've changed my code and still no luck unfortunately. Perhaps there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: @AaronBoclet Can you make sure your code is the same as mine? Including the xaml page. There's only one Grid as the root panel.

Comment: Brilliant it all works, I was passing through the wrong control in the last line in GetVisualStateGroups. Also works without using any XAML too. Thanks very much.